# partial cumulative sum in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a `numpy` array (or `pandas` `Series` if it makes it any easier), which looks like this:

```
foo = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

I want to transform into an array

```
bar = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4,0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

where the entry is how many steps you need to walk to the left to find a `1` in `foo`.

Now, obviously one can write a loop to compute `bar` from `foo`, but this will be bog slow. Is there anything more clever one can do?

**UPDATE** The `pd.Series` solution is around 7 times slower than the pure `numpy` solution. The stupid loop solution is very slow (no surprise), but when jit compiled with `numba` is as fast as the `numpy` solution.

Answer (score 9):

You could do `cumcount` with `pandas`

```
s = pd.Series(foo)
bar = s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount().to_numpy()
Out[13]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option, specifically for the shared example, with numpy:

```py
# get positions where value is 1
pos = foo.nonzero()[0]
# need this when computing the cumsum
values = np.diff(pos) - 1
arr = np.ones(foo.size, dtype=int)
arr[0] = 0
arr[pos[1:]] = -values
arr.cumsum()

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: A very pretty solution.